# Reset class variables in a python class?

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, scope

- I have a class and two separate functions
- function replace_null in class ElNino is trying to replace null values with running average
- average_humidity_without_Null is trying to calculate the average using ElNino class replace_null method
- non_null_dataFrame function is to create a dataframe of with non null variables

While running the code, I am calling (e_n_row.replace_null('humidity') on two occasion:

1. average_humidity_without_Null()
2. non_null_dataFrame

The output of first method ends on:

```
col is humidity, sum is 52608.480000000054 , count is 623, average is 84.44378812199045 and the value is 95.5
col is humidity, sum is 52701.880000000056 , count is 624, average is 84.45814102564111 and the value is 93.4
```

After this, I am executing #2 method, and the output starts on

```
col is humidity, sum is 52785.380000000056 , count is 625, average is 84.45660800000009 and the value is 83.5
col is humidity, sum is 52871.78000000006 , count is 626, average is 84.45971246006398 and the value is 86.4
col is humidity, sum is 52954.78000000006 , count is 627, average is 84.45738437001604 and the value is 83.0
```

The code block for reference is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

class ElNinoData(object):
    add = 0
    counter = 0
    average = 0
    # methods
    def __init__(self , object):
        self.object = object

    def replace_null(self , i): 
        if not math.isnan(self.object[i]):
            ElNinoData.add += self.object[i]
            ElNinoData.counter += 1
            ElNinoData.average = ElNinoData.add/ElNinoData.counter
            print('col is {}, sum is {} , count is {}, average is {} and the value is {}'.format(i, ElNinoData.add,  ElNinoData.counter ,  ElNinoData.average, self.object[i]))
        else:
            self.object[i] = ElNinoData.average 
            print('<------>\ncol is {}, sum is {} , count is {}, average is {} and the value is {} \n<------>'.format(i, ElNinoData.add,  ElNinoData.counter ,  ElNinoData.average , self.object[i]))
        return self.object[i]

    def get_humidity(self):
        return self.object['humidity']

def get_obj_it():
    lst = ['bouy','day','latitude','longitude','zon_winds','mer_winds','humidity','air_temp','s_s_temp']
    df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\suel.abbasi\\Downloads\\elnino.gz', sep='\s+', header=None)
    df.columns = lst
    df = df.replace({'.':np.nan})
    for i , j in df.iterrows():
        yield ElNinoData(pd.to_numeric(j))
'''
I have added a small piece of code in ElNinoData Class, 
that will replace all the null values with running average of non null values.
'''        
def average_humidity_without_Null():    
    e_n_generator = get_obj_it()

    count = 0;
    hum_sum = 0;

    for e_n_row in e_n_generator:
        count += 1
        hum_sum += e_n_row.replace_null('humidity')
        #print(count , e_n_row.replace_null('humidity'))

#    print("Mean Humidity is '{}' Percent".format(hum_sum/count))
average_humidity_without_Null()

# function to create a new dataframe will all the null values replace - it can be improved
def non_null_dataFrame():
    generator = get_obj_it()
    latitude , longitude , zon_winds , mer_winds, air_temp , ss_temp , bouy , day , humidity = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    lst = ['day','bouy','latitude','longitude','zon_winds','mer_winds','air_temp','s_s_temp','humidity']

    for e_n_row in generator:
        humidity.append(e_n_row.replace_null('humidity'))
        '''
        longitude.append(e_n_row.replace_null('longitude'))
        zon_winds.append(e_n_row.replace_null('zon_winds'))
        mer_winds.append(e_n_row.replace_null('mer_winds'))
        air_temp.append(e_n_row.replace_null('air_temp'))
        ss_temp.append(e_n_row.replace_null('s_s_temp'))
        latitude.append(e_n_row.replace_null('latitude'))
        bouy.append(e_n_row.replace_null('bouy'))
        day.append(e_n_row.replace_null('day'))'''
    '''     
    df['day'] = day
    df['bouy'] = bouy
    df['latitude'] = latitude
    df['longitude'] = longitude
    df['zon_winds'] = zon_winds
    df['mer_winds'] = mer_winds
    df['air_temp'] = air_temp
    df['s_s_temp'] = ss_temp'''
    df['humidity'] = humidity

    return df
non_null_dataFrame()
```

The thing that is bothering me:

- How can I reset my class variables for different function calls, in my case the variables add, counter and average continued there count when called for different methods?

Comment: That's a lot of code and I didn't go through it - a smaller example would help! - but why are these class variables? It seems they should be instance variables set in `__init__` (e.g., self.count = 0) and any time your code wants a "fresh" version, it creates another instance.

Comment: I tried the self.count method, but the problem here is that ElNinoData.average = ElNinoData.add/ElNinoData.counter part of the code is not working.

In self.count method, my counter is always 1 and my add variable is not summing and its taking the latest value that is passed to the method

Comment: Likely they also should be instance variables. `ElNinoData.add` becomes `self.add`, etc... I can't run your code, so I can't write you an answer (see my suggestion about a better example). When you make a class variable, there is only 1 copy of that variable shared by all of the instances. Class variables are rare. It seems like you'd like these calculations to be unique per instance so they should all be instance variables. (self.foo).

Comment: you'd like these calculations to be unique per instance so they should all be instance variables >> thats true. Can you please give a small example along the def replace_null(self , i) lines?